# Winrt - unzip file hierarchy

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm dealing with unzipping zip file with some hierarchy of files to Local folder. I tried [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) but extension method **ExtractToDirectory** is not supported on winrt. Some other possibilities are DotNetZip and SharpZipLib but these libraries are not supported on winrt too.

Zip hierarchy file can look like this (I assume depth of the hierarchy max 2):
folder1/picture1.jpg 
folder1/picture2.jpg 
folder2/picture1.jpg 
folder2/picture2.jpg

Some simplified code sample :

```
var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("..../file.zip");

var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var option = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;

var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("file.zip", option);
Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, data);

// zip is saved to Local folder and now I need extract files hierarchy from this zip
```

Do you have some clever and simple solution for this issue? Do you know some useful library, nuget package for winrt or Portable class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some extension methods I have to handle this stuff using ZipArchive.

```
public static async Task<IStorageItem> CreatePath(this StorageFolder folder, string fileLocation, CreationCollisionOption fileCollisionOption, CreationCollisionOption folderCollisionOption)
{
    var localFilePath = PathHelper.ToLocalPath(fileLocation).Replace(PathHelper.ToLocalPath(folder.Path), "");
    if (localFilePath.Length > 0 && (localFilePath[0] == '/' || localFilePath[0] == '\\'))
    {
        localFilePath = localFilePath.Remove(0, 1);
    }

    if (localFilePath.Length == 0)
    {
        return folder;
    }

    var separatorIndex = localFilePath.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '/', '\\' });
    if (separatorIndex == -1)
    {
        return await folder.CreateFileAsync(localFilePath, fileCollisionOption);
    }
    else
    {
        var folderName = localFilePath.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
        var subFolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, folderCollisionOption);
        return await subFolder.CreatePath(fileLocation.Substring(separatorIndex + 1), fileCollisionOption, folderCollisionOption);
    }
}

public static async Task ExtractToFolderAsync(this ZipArchive archive, StorageFolder folder)
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        var storageItem = await folder.CreatePathAsync(entry.FullName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile file;
        if ((file = storageItem as StorageFile) != null)
        {
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    await entryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about solution like this. But thank you for your code.

Comment: @Jon R Can you please describe PathHelper class..?

Comment: Where did you get PathHelper from? any links?

Comment: PathHelper is a custom class.  It does basic string manipulation to get a local style path from an absolute one.  More or less it translates "/" to "\\" and gets adjusts the path to remove any ".." and "." folder segments